# How to define a concept of a object that is can be structured binding?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I want to define a `concept` that can detect whether the type `T` can be *structured binding* or not:

```
template <typename T>
concept two_elements_structured_bindable = requires (T t) {
  auto [x, y] = t;
};
```

but this cannot be compiled. Is there a proper way to define a `concept` like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

There are three cases in structured bindings:

1. Arrays. That's easy enough to detect.
2. Tuple-like. You can easily check if `std::tuple_size<E>::value` is valid, and then check if `std::tuple_element<I, E>::type` is valid as a type for all the right types. But the `get` case is harder since you have to deal with member vs non-member... but otherwise I think doable.
3. Types which have all public (yeah yeah, technically accessible) members as direct members of the same class. This is impossible to detect with current technology. `magic_get` can, I think, handle `struct X { int a, b; };` but neither `struct Y : X { };` nor `struct Z { X& x; };` You would need to have proper reflection to check this case.

As of C++20, you would need some kind of compiler intrinsic to do this.

Comment: Wait for C++23 reflection.

Answer (score 8):

**With C++20**, you can define a `concept` that would identify *C-style arrays* and *tuple-like types* as *structure bindable*. But it cannot identify types which are being structure bindable based on public-only fields.

Possible *concepts* that can be implemented (see full implementation [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ocox9sqed)):

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
concept structure_bindable = 
    (std::is_array_v<T> && (std::extent_v<T> == N)) ||
    ((std::tuple_size_v<T> == N) && has_get_for_size<T, N>::value);

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
concept structure_bindable_with = 
    structure_bindable<T, sizeof...(Ts)>
    && is_get_N<T, Ts...>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});

template<typename T, size_t N, typename Expected>
concept structure_bindable_with_N = 
    structure_bindable<T, N>
    && is_get_N<T, N-1, Expected>();
```

---

A side note: it can be achieved with compiler intrinsic features
[for example - here for clang](https://godbolt.org/z/vEhbres3G) (courtesy of Avi Lachmish).

---

My dear friend [@Dvir Yitzchaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/621176/dvir-yitzchaki) pointed out to me that **based on the proposed pattern matching syntax by Herb Sutter**, you can identify all *stucture bindable* cases, based on `as` check inside a `concept`, **not yet in C++20**, but already implemented [in Circle compiler](https://github.com/seanbaxter/circle/blob/master/pattern/README.md).

Herb Sutter together with the Circle compiler implementer Sean Baxter, presented the idea of the `is` and `as` pattern matching, as part of Herb's talk at CppCon 2021, [see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raB_289NxBk&t=18m49s).

Based on their talk, Dvir came to the idea that I later elaborated into this [working implementation on Circle compiler](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/779drnx3d):

```
template <typename T>
concept two_elements_structured_bindable = structured_bindable<T>
    && !single_element_structured_bindable<T>
    && two_elements_structured_bindable_<T>;
```

Based on this:

```
template <typename T>
concept structured_bindable = requires (T t) {
    t as [...]; // note: not supported by C++20
};

template <typename T>
struct single_element_structured_bindable_wrapper {
    auto first() {
        auto[a, ...] = std::declval<T>();  // note: not supported by C++20
        return a;
    }
    using first_type = decltype(first());
};

template <typename T>
concept single_element_structured_bindable = structured_bindable<T>
    && requires (T t) {
    {t as [single_element_structured_bindable_wrapper<T>::first_type]};
};
```

And:

```
template <typename T>
struct two_elements_structured_bindable_wrapper {
    auto first() {
        auto[a, ...] = std::declval<T>(); // note: not supported by C++20
        return a;
    }
    auto second() {
        auto[a, b, ...] = std::declval<T>(); // note: not supported by C++20
        return b;
    }
    using first_type = decltype(first());
    using second_type = decltype(second());
};

template <typename T>
concept two_elements_structured_bindable_ = requires (T t) {
    {t as [
            two_elements_structured_bindable_wrapper<T>::first_type,
            two_elements_structured_bindable_wrapper<T>::second_type
          ]};
};
```

Note that it supports checking all type of structure bindings:

```
static_assert(!two_elements_structured_bindable<std::tuple<int, int, int>>);
static_assert(!two_elements_structured_bindable<std::tuple<int>>);
static_assert(!two_elements_structured_bindable<int>);
static_assert(two_elements_structured_bindable<std::tuple<int, int>>);

static_assert(!two_elements_structured_bindable<std::array<int, 3>>);
static_assert(!two_elements_structured_bindable<std::array<int, 1>>);
static_assert(two_elements_structured_bindable<std::array<int, 2>>);

struct Vec3 { float x, y, z; };    
static_assert(!two_elements_structured_bindable<Vec3>);

struct Vec2 { float x, y; };
static_assert(two_elements_structured_bindable<Vec2>);
```

---

After presenting above solution in [a CoreCpp meetup](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1ZFOBqPKccy5mTggr207NrKsyNYI7l2Ec65UGAUaD40w/edit?usp=sharing), Dvir poured cold water on my solution, with [a much shorter one](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r6oKnob46):

```
struct anything // std::any is not good enough for that
{
    template<typename T>
    anything(T&&) {}
};

template<typename T>
concept twople = requires(T t)
{
    t as [anything, anything];
};
```

I still keep the long solution above, as it has in my view some value for other implementations.

---

If you want to constraint on the types you would bound with, you may prefer going with another approach, which again relies on pattern matching syntax, with another proposed `concept`:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
concept TupleLike = requires (T t) {
    {t as [Ts...]}; // note: not supported by C++20
};
```

That can allow a constraint like this:

```
void foo(TupleLike<double, double, double> auto tup) {
    auto[a, b, c] = tup; // 3 doubles
    // ...
}
```

[Above code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zhqn4aeYK) is again based on pattern matching syntax, not yet available in C++ (as of C++20), but already implemented in Circle compiler.

---

Now, in order to support a more generic concept for `structured_bindable<Size>`, there is a need to use another future C++ feature, which allows `sizeof...(T)` on a `T` that is not a variadic pack but rather any structure bindable type. This feature might be part of [p1858](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1858r2.html) or a related proposal. And again, it is [already supported in Circle compiler](https://github.com/seanbaxter/circle/tree/master/universal#object-lengths).

This allows [this very simple implementation](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sTcxWafdo) (again, proposed by Dvir):

```
template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
concept has_size_of = sizeof...(T) == SIZE;

template <typename T>
concept structured_bindable = requires (T t) {
    t as [...];
};

template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
concept structured_bindable_with = structured_bindable<T> && has_size_of<T, SIZE>;
```

Thus allowing constraining on being bindable with an exact given number, e.g.:

```
void foo(const structured_bindable_with<2> auto& v) {
    const auto&[a, b] = v;
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
}
```

In fact, if being able to provide `sizeof...` becomes a feature that says you are a structure bindable type (including variadic pack by itself!), then above concept [can simply become](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oWPW5hxqq):

```
template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
concept structured_bindable_with = (sizeof...(T) == SIZE);
```

Comment: Is it possible for [P2392](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2392r1.pdf) to make it into C++23?