# How to check if type instance can be used inside structured binding declaration?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae

How to write e.g. `is_structured_bindable_2<T>` in C++17? It should only be `true_type` if `auto [f1, f2] = x;` compiles where `x` is an instance of `T`;

```cpp
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_structured_bindable_2<T> : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_structured_bindable_2<T, ???>
    : std::true_type {};
```

I couldn't find how to check if a statement (not an expression) compiles in SFINAE *in C++17*. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63369361/how-to-define-a-concept-of-a-object-that-is-can-be-structured-binding?

Comment: @康桓瑋 yeah, thanks, I guess it's not possible :(